# access elements in array of arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, variables, arraylist

I am printing an array of arraylist which contains 2d array.

`ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Array>>> sols;`

I am trying to print this:

`System.out.print(sols.get(0).get(0).get(0));`

was expecting a 2d array as it was the lowest level of the variable

I get this instead

`app.Array@42037252`

How can I print the specified 2d array?

**EDIT**

this is my `Array` class

```
public class Array {
    int[][] array;
    public Array(int[][] initialArray){
         array = initialArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not being very specific about the case.. How do you want to store a solution in an array?

Comment: The class app.Array does not implement toString() so the default Object's toString is being called and "class@hexhashcode" is being printed. Did you write the "Array" class?

Comment: @CrazyGirl can you post the Array class code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are getting is the default representation of your `Array` object provided by [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method.

I suppose `app.Array` is a custom class implemented by you.

So to print out your 2d array in a more intuitive way you need to override the `toString()` method in your class.

For example:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return Arrays.deepToString(array);
}
```